# difficulty setting up consumer test pact python

Tags: python, pact

Im trying to set up a consumer test with Pact, but Im struggling.  If someone could help me where Im going wrong it would be appreciated.

The file I am trying to test is as follows:

```py
import requests

from orders_service.exceptions import (
    APIIntegrationError,
    InvalidActionError
)


class OrderItem:
    def __init__(self, id, product, quantity, size):
        self.id = id
        self.product = product
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.size = size

    def dict(self):
        return {
            'product': self.product,
            'size': self.size,
            'quantity': self.quantity
        }


class Order:
    def __init__(self, id, created, items, status, schedule_id=None,
                 delivery_id=None, order_=None):
        self._order = order_
        self._id = id
        self._created = created
        self.items = [OrderItem(**item) for item in items]
        self.status = status
        self.schedule_id = schedule_id
        self.delivery_id = delivery_id

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id or self._order.id

    @property
    def created(self):
        return self._created or self._order.created

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self._status or self._order.status

    def cancel(self):
        if self.status == 'progress':
            response = requests.get(
                f'http://localhost:3001/kitchen/schedule/{self.schedule_id}/cancel',
                data={'order': self.items}
            )
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return
            raise APIIntegrationError(
                f'Could not cancel order with id {self.id}'
            )
        if self.status == 'delivery':
            raise InvalidActionError(f'Cannot cancel order with id {self.id}')

    def pay(self):
        response = requests.post(
            'http://localhost:3001/payments', data={'order_id': self.id}
        )
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return
        raise APIIntegrationError(
            f'Could not process payment for order with id {self.id}'
        )

    def schedule(self):
        response = requests.post(
            'http://localhost:3000/kitchen/schedule',
            data={'order': [item.dict() for item in self.items]}
        )
        if response.status_code == 201:
            return response.json()['id']
        raise APIIntegrationError(
            f'Could not schedule order with id {self.id}'
        )

    def dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'order': [item.dict() for item in self.items],
            'status': self.status,
            'created': self.created,
        }
```

The consumer test I just can't get it to stage where it is publishing the contract.  There are 2 areas Im not too familiar with firstly the python fixture. Im really unsure what needs to go here or how to do that and lastly the "consumer.cancel()" at the very bottom of the test.

Some help getting me set up and one the way would be greatly appreciated.  Here is what I wrote for the test:

```py
import atexit
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import os
from uuid import UUID
import requests
import pytest
import subprocess

from pact import Consumer, Like, Provider, Term, Format

from orders_service.orders import Order, OrderItem

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# If publishing the Pact(s), they will be submitted to the Pact Broker here.
# For the purposes of this example, the broker is started up as a fixture defined
# in conftest.py. For normal usage this would be self-hosted or using Pactflow.
PACT_BROKER_URL = "https://xxx.pactflow.io/"
PACT_BROKER_USERNAME = xxx
PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD = xxx

# Define where to run the mock server, for the consumer to connect to. These
# are the defaults so may be omitted
PACT_MOCK_HOST = "localhost"
PACT_MOCK_PORT = 1234

# Where to output the JSON Pact files created by any tests
PACT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


@pytest.fixture
def consumer() -> Order.cancel:
    # return Order.cancel("http://{host}:{port}".format(host=PACT_MOCK_HOST, "port=PACT_MOCK_PORT))
    order = [OrderItem(**{"id":1, "product":"coffee", "size":"big", "quantity":2})]
    payload = Order(id=UUID, created=datetime.now, items=order, status="progress")
    return Order.cancel(payload)



@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def pact(request):
    """Setup a Pact Consumer, which provides the Provider mock service. This
    will generate and optionally publish Pacts to the Pact Broker"""
    # When publishing a Pact to the Pact Broker, a version number of the Consumer
    # is required, to be able to construct the compatability matrix between the
    # Consumer versions and Provider versions
    # version = request.config.getoption("--publish-pact")
    # publish = True if version else False

    pact = Consumer("UserServiceClient", version=1).has_pact_with(
        Provider("UserService"),
        host_name=PACT_MOCK_HOST,
        port=PACT_MOCK_PORT,
        pact_dir=PACT_DIR,
        publish_to_broker=True,
        broker_base_url=PACT_BROKER_URL,
        broker_username=PACT_BROKER_USERNAME,
        broker_password=PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD,
    )

    pact.start_service()

    # Make sure the Pact mocked provider is stopped when we finish, otherwise
    # port 1234 may become blocked
    atexit.register(pact.stop_service)

    yield pact

    # This will stop the Pact mock server, and if publish is True, submit Pacts
    # to the Pact Broker
    pact.stop_service()

    # Given we have cleanly stopped the service, we do not want to re-submit the
    # Pacts to the Pact Broker again atexit, since the Broker may no longer be
    # available if it has been started using the --run-broker option, as it will
    # have been torn down at that point
    pact.publish_to_broker = False


def test_cancel_scheduled_order(pact, consumer):
        expected = \
       {
          "id": "1e54e244-d0ab-46ed-a88a-b9e6037655ef",
          "order": [
            {
              "product": "coffee",
              "quantity": 1,
              "size": "small"
            }
          ],
          "scheduled": "Wed, 22 Jun 2022 09:21:26 GMT",
          "status": "cancelled"
        }


        (pact
        .given('A scheduled order exists and it is not cancelled already')
        .upon_receiving('a request for cancellation')
        .with_request('get', f'http://localhost:3001/kitchen/schedule/{Like(12343)}/cancel')
        .will_respond_with(200, body=Like(expected)))

        with pact:
            payload = Order(UUID, datetime.now, {"product":"coffee", "size":"large", "quantity":1}, "progress")
            print(payload)
            response = consumer.cancel(payload)
            assert response['status'] == "cancelled"
        
        pact.verify()
```

Also I originally had(adapted from the example in pact):

```
    # return Order.cancel("http://{host}:{port}".format(host=PACT_MOCK_HOST, "port=PACT_MOCK_PORT))
```

but i'm not sure how that works

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

```
.with_request('get', f'http://localhost:3001/kitchen/schedule/{Like(12343)}/cancel')
```

1. The `Like` matcher is a function that returns an object. Adding this within a string is likely to cause issues when it is stringified
2. You don't need to put the protocol and host portion here - just the path e.g.:

```py
.with_request(method='GET', path='/kitchen/schedule/bc72e917-4af1-4e39-b897-1eda6d006b18/cancel', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'} ...)
```

If you want to use a matcher on the path, it needs to be on the string as a whole e.g. `Regex('/kitchen/schedule/([0-9]+)/cancel')` (this is not a real regex, but hopefully you get the idea).

3. I can’t see in this code where it calls the actual mock service. I’ve removed the commented items for readability:

```
       (pact
        .given('A scheduled order exists and it is not cancelled already')
        .upon_receiving('a request for cancellation')
        .with_request(method='GET', path='/kitchen/schedule/bc72e917-4af1-4e39-b897-1eda6d006b18/cancel', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},)
        .will_respond_with(200, body=Like(expected)))

        with pact:
            # this needs to be sending a request to
            # http://localhost:1234/kitchen/schedule/bc72e917-4af1-4e39-b897-1eda6d006b18/cancel
            response = consumer.cancel() 
        
        pact.verify()
```

The definition of the function you are calling doesn't make any HTTP request to the pact mock service, it just returns a canned response.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def consumer() -> Order.cancel:
    # return Order.cancel("http://{host}:{port}".format(host=PACT_MOCK_HOST, "port=PACT_MOCK_PORT))
    order = [OrderItem(**{"id":1, "product":"coffee", "size":"big", "quantity":2})]
    payload = Order(id=UUID, created=datetime.now, items=order, status="progress")
    return Order.cancel(payload)
```

For a Pact test to pass, you need to demonstrate your code actually calls the correct HTTP endpoints with the right data, and that your code can handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Matt.
I did this in the end:
```
response = requests.get(pact.uri + '/kitchen/schedule/273429e2-e513-4df7-95bc-eeaad7e0e5aa/cancel')
            response = response.json()
            assert response['status'] == "cancelled"
        pact.verify()
```